# Redis sentinel failover configuration issue

Tags: redis, haproxy, high-availability, sentinel, redis-sentinel

I have using Redis-Sentinel architecture on my enviroment. I have 3 different servers. I installed and configured redis and sentinel both of them. Basically i have three redis and 3 sentinels run on 3 server at the same time. All servers run on Centos 7. I am using Redis 4.0.10. There is not any network restrictions. I disabled selinux and firewall. It looks good but i am having a problem with failover when i stop my master redis process on my master machine.

My master machine ip is : 10.0.23.242

Slave 1: 10.0.23.243

Slave 2: 10.0.23.244

```
     [root@ibs23redistest1 redis]# redis-cli -h 10.0.23.242 -p 26379
10.0.23.242:26379> sentinel masters
    1) "name"
    2) "redis-cluster"
    3) "ip"
    4) "10.0.23.242"
    5) "port"
    6) "6379"
    7) "runid"
    8) "07b11d5e7cd7aa6efeb6d40a2371f5533529e308"
    9) "flags"
   10) "master"
   11) "link-pending-commands"
   12) "0"
   13) "link-refcount"
   14) "1"
   15) "last-ping-sent"
   16) "0"
   17) "last-ok-ping-reply"
   18) "1019"
   19) "last-ping-reply"
   20) "1019"
   21) "down-after-milliseconds"
   22) "5000"
   23) "info-refresh"
   24) "7950"
   25) "role-reported"
   26) "master"
   27) "role-reported-time"
   28) "258002"
   29) "config-epoch"
   30) "0"
   31) "num-slaves"
   32) "2"
   33) "num-other-sentinels"
   34) "2"
   35) "quorum"
   36) "2"
   37) "failover-timeout"
   38) "10000"
   39) "parallel-syncs"
   40) "1"
My configs are below

-------------- Master redis.conf --------------
bind 10.0.23.242
port 6379
dir .

-------------- Master sentinel.conf --------------
bind 10.0.23.242
#daemonize yes
port 26379
sentinel myid 68c0aadd673285fcfd87838e0ce4f14e90617371
sentinel monitor redis-cluster 10.0.23.242 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redis-cluster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout redis-cluster 10000
sentinel config-epoch redis-cluster 0
#sentinel logfile /var/log/redis-sentinel.log
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
dir "/etc/redis"
sentinel leader-epoch redis-cluster 0
sentinel known-slave redis-cluster 10.0.23.244 6379
sentinel known-slave redis-cluster 10.0.23.243 6379
sentinel known-sentinel redis-cluster 10.0.23.243 26379 58051360cb3a05b3cc5b2b093041ce8d11555598
sentinel known-sentinel redis-cluster 10.0.23.244 26379 6056478d3dbd7a370e297c055ba66193a91f32ba
sentinel current-epoch 0
-------------- Slave 2 redis.conf --------------
bind 10.0.23.244
port 6379
dir .
slaveof 10.0.23.242 6379

-------------- Slave 2 sentinel.conf --------------
bind 10.0.23.244
port 26379
sentinel myid 6056478d3dbd7a370e297c055ba66193a91f32ba
sentinel monitor redis-cluster 10.0.23.244 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redis-cluster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout redis-cluster 10000
sentinel config-epoch redis-cluster 0
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
dir "/root"
sentinel leader-epoch redis-cluster 0
sentinel known-sentinel redis-cluster 10.0.23.242 26379 68c0aadd673285fcfd87838e0ce4f14e90617371
sentinel current-epoch 0



-------------- Slave 1 redis.conf --------------
bind 10.0.23.243
port 6379
dir .
slaveof 10.0.23.242 6379

-------------- Slave 1 sentinel.conf --------------
bind 10.0.23.243
port 26379
sentinel myid 58051360cb3a05b3cc5b2b093041ce8d11555598
sentinel monitor redis-cluster 10.0.23.243 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redis-cluster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout redis-cluster 10000
sentinel config-epoch redis-cluster 0
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
dir "/root"
sentinel leader-epoch redis-cluster 0
sentinel known-sentinel redis-cluster 10.0.23.242 26379 68c0aadd673285fcfd87838e0ce4f14e90617371
sentinel current-epoch 0
```

Comment: does the failover not happen when you stop the master? have you renamed some redis commands

Comment: no did not rename or link any command on redis. Why do you asking ?

Comment: Both your sentinels should monitor the master and not their own IP right? `sentinel monitor redis-cluster 10.0.23.242 6379 2`. You have the `sentinel.conf` for the slaves monitoring their own IP, hence I don't think they'd failover automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Both your slave sentinels should monitor the master IP and not their own IP.

`sentinel monitor redis-cluster 10.0.23.242 6379 2` for both slaves.

You have the `sentinel.conf` for the slaves monitoring their own IP, hence I don't think they would failover automatically.